# NDK stack trace on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-ndk, stack-trace, ndk-stack

I'd like to analyze stack trace from Android NDK. How do I read it on Windows machine, please?

I know there is a python script but I have a hard time to run that on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can do stack trace by running this command in cmd:

```
adb logcat | C:\path\to\one\of\your\ndks\ndk-stack -sym C:\path\to\your\project\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a
```

of course you should choose any other architecture version in obj folder instead of armeabi-v7a, based on you android device that you are debugging on.